# Safe same ID in different tables of database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple shop.
When an order is submitted, the order it gets stored into my database. The ORDER ID is created with AUTO_INCREMENT.

I need now to store my ORDER ID also in another table, to relate the products to it. What is the best way to safe my order ID into two different tables, so that they can relate to each other?

Comment: generally you would have an `order_id` column in your order items table which is a foreign key to your orders table.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using mysqli (you lack information), have a look at [mysqli_insert_id](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php) which will give you the ID your row got given in the orders table, you can then reuse this in the next table to match them up.

Comment: yes I am using mysql. Thank you very much. Sorry, I am a very beginner of php and mysql. So if I understand you: 1. I store my order into the database, 2. an order ID is automatically generated 3. In php I am using mysqli_insert_id, this means I grab the latest ID of that specific table and put it into another table. But how can I tell my products now that they have all the same order ID?